# I want to load default image in picturebox if the user does not select an image in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, embedded-resource

I am developing a window form in C#. In my window form there is a picture box. I want if the user does not select an image then the default image will be load in picture box which is save in my project folder.

thanks in advance

Comment: please show some code... what have you tried ?

Comment: The question is how i will be load default image if user do not select any image?

Comment: @bilal What CKoenig is getting at is that you didn't actually ask a question. You just told us what you wanted. That only works at Mickey D's...

Answer (score 6):

I guess you want to know how you can get the picture from the project folder right?

First add the picture to you project (add existing item) and set the Build Action to Embedded Resource:
[image]

then the following code do the trick:

```
        private void SetPicture()
        {
            var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            using (var imgStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("DataGrid.TestImage.jpg"))
            {
                var img = new Bitmap(imgStream);
                Picturebox.Image = img;
            }
        }
```

where "DataGrid" is MY project-name (you have to insert your own) and "TestImage.jpg" is the name of your Image (if you put it into a folder you might have to give the foldername too).
Picturebox is a PictureBox-Control I set the image to.

Comment: Why not just use Image.FromFile ?

Comment: of course you can use a ImageList too - this way you don't have to write any code. But the snippet with the GetManifestResourceStream will work for any embedded resource and it comes handy from time to time.

Comment: @Neowizard: does Image.FromFile work for an embedded resource? Never tried. I interpreted the question the way that he wants to have the std-image in his assembly. If it is shiped with the assembly you are certainly right.

Comment: But Neowizard has some point - you can use var img=Image.FromStream(imgStream) instead of the newing up of the bitmap - this might be clearer and better design

Answer (score 0):

Either set an image in the designer and override it in code

for instance you can place this after user selection:

```
if (someConditionIndicatingUserAction)
    pictureBoxControlName.Image = UserSelectedImage;
```

Or, you can store a default value in a variable and set the picturebox image to it (if the user selects nothing, you don't change the value, and if he does, change it accordingly)